# Expected value of coin flipping game with biased coin, bias unknown

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we have a biased coin with unknown probability of landing heads. We play a game consisting of 100 rounds, in which, every round, we must bet $1 on the outcome, in a 1 to 1 payout. What is the expected value of this game?

My initial thought was to observe the first few flips and conditional on those flips, estimate the posterior distribution using a Beta-Binomial model and appropriately bet. However, we must bet $1 each round from the beginning.

Is there any logical way to approach this problem either from a frequentist or Bayesian framework?

Comment: A Bayesian framework could be to assume the prior probability distribution of landing heads as a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: In this context, I imagine the strategy that maximizes the expected value is to bet on the result that occurred more often.

Comment: @P.S.Dester Assume that the actual probability of landing Heads, for this biased coin, is a random number from $~(0,1).~$  Assume further that the strategy in your 2nd comment is followed.  Then, what is the expected value of the game?

Comment: The expected value depends on the strategy. The question probably is how to maximize this.

Comment: Until we are quite sure which side is preferred , betting the last result is a good idea. If some side has a clear advantage , only bet on this side.

Comment: It is better to bet on whatever has been seen the most times, so after HHT you would still bet heads.  Once you have this strategy you can compute the value of the game as a function of the probability of heads, then find the expected value over your distribution of that probability.

Comment: @RossMillikan Please take this comment with a large grain of salt, since I am uneducated in formal Probability Theory.  The point of my first comment is that I see no simple way to compute expected value here, given that the coin's bias is unknown.  I suppose that one approach would be to assume that there exists  a fixed $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}},~$ such that the coin's bias is some element in $~\displaystyle \left\{ ~\frac{1}{n}, ~\frac{2}{n}, ~\cdots, \frac{n-1}{n} ~\right\}.~$ ...see next comment

Comment: @RossMillikan So, for each of the $~(n-1)~$ *originally* equally likely bias values, you would have to examine each of the $~2^{100}~$ possible coin flip sequences, computing the probability of each sequence occurring, based on the individually assumed bias.  Then, you could compute the expectation, as a function of $~n.~$  Then, you could take the limit, as $~n \to \infty~$ of this expectation.  My guess is that formal Probability Theory has already attacked/elegantly-cleaned up this math.  However, to someone uneducated in formal theory, like me, I imagine that the math looks fairly ugly.

Comment: Given a bias you can compute the probability that you have any given number of heads from the binomial distribution.  If the probability of a head is $p$ and the number of heads out of $100$ is $h$ the probability is ${100 \choose h}h^p(1-h)^{1-p}$

Comment: What I don't know how to do cleanly is to compute the expectation at a given $p$.  If $p=0.6,$ say, you might get tails on the first throw and then bet tails on the second.  Eventually you will always bet heads, but how long that takes on average is hard to assess.  Once you do this, you can average the expectations over the pdf of $p$